# ngrx/data: best way to have multiple api roots?

Tags: ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I would need to target different api endpoint roots from different angular modules.

For example

- http://server:port/user-api from User module
- http://server:port/admin-api from Admin module
- http://server:port/checkout-api from Cart module
  and so on.

From what I see, the api root called by ngrx/data can be changed but only globally, by means of `DefaultDataServiceConfig` in app.module

How can I have different api roots in different Angular modules?

At the moment I am using a `CustomizeHttpUrlGenerator` to change the urls based on a naming convention of mine, but I guess there's a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a provider and change it when you want.

```js
const API_ROOT = new InjectionToken<string>('BASE_HREF', {
    factory: () => 'http://server:port/user-api ',
})
```

then for admin

```js
...
providers: [
  {
    provide: API_ROOT,
    useValue: 'http://server:port/admin-api',
  }
],
...
```

and somewhere in code

```js
constructor(@Inject(API_ROOT) public readonly apiRoot: string) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entry per Entity in the entityResource method of the HttpUrlGenerator.

Hence in the User module for the User entity you would have

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDataService extends DefaultDataService<User> {

constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator) {
        httpUrlGenerator.entityResource('User','http://server:port/user-api' );
        super('User', http, httpUrlGenerator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to malc answer, I suggest you override the config of the DataService on a case by case scenario.

```js
export class UserDataService extends DefaultDataService<User> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator, defaultConfig: DefaultDataServiceConfig) {
        super('User', http, httpUrlGenerator, { ...defaultConfig, root: 'http://server:port/user-api' })
    }
}
```

This is less hacky than preemptively setting the knownHttpUrls of the DefaultDataService.